# Comparison of various Pitivi video editor project settings

Tags: pitivi

I love Pitivi video editor for being able to deal with so many different video formats. Under `project`->`project settings`->`export to`, there are multiple containers, video codecs and audio codecs. What are the pros and cons of these options?

Comment: This isn't really an Ubuntu question, but a video/audio question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I Would use MKV For High quality as it is open source and has more options than any other format [Comparison of container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats). As far as mobile or streaming is concerned I would use webm as its also open source and is designed to be streamed and is backed by google (chrome os, android etc.....) and for everyone else flv.

Hope this helps.